# Does Firestore database count more document reads when applying multiple conditions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider this example

```
citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CO").where("name", "==", "Denver").get().then( res => ... );
```

Assume there are 10 documents satisfying the first condition, 20 documents satisfying the second condition and only 5 documents satisfying the both conditions.

How many document reads does Firestore count ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How many document reads does Firestore count?

You'll be charged with a number of document reads that is equal with the number of documents that are returned by your query. So if your combined query will return 5 elements, you'll only be charged with 5 reads.

Comment: There is a limitation only upto one query with multiple `'array-contains'` condition to the same query. Do you know how can we avoid that?

Comment: There is no way you can avoid that limitation. You can only use a single `array-contains` condition in a query.

Comment: @BumuthuDilshan If you want to query with multiple `array-contains` conditions, you will need to trigger several queries to Firestore (each one having one `array-contains` condition) and merge them in your front-end.

Comment: If you take the approach that Renaud suggests, each query **will** of course be reading documents from the database, and thus you will be charged for each document read by each of those queries, even if you end up only showing a subset of those documents to your user.